# Linking Containers / Building Images In Docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker

I'm going to do my best to describe what I'm trying to accomplish and hopefully someone could help me out with the process I can use to get what I'm wanting done. Not really a step by step, but as I said just a process so I can kind of wrap my head around what needs to get done.

I have built a NodeJS blogging application. It requires the use of MongoDB. What I am attempting to do is have my dockerfile/mynodeblog image and dockerfile/mongodb and link the containers together (I do not want to include the installation of MongoDB in my blog Dockerfile, I would specifically like to link the containers). However I'm somewhat being caught up in a catch 22.

My node app again requires MongoDB which isn't a problem when just installing MongoDB, installing my node blog, and then running my node blog the old fashioned way. The problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to build my node blog into a Dockerfile and build out the image. Unfortunately the image will never be built out successfully because it needs MongoDB to finish. But MongoDB is going to be in another container!

If that made any sense at all, I would appreciate any feedback on how I could even begin to approach the problem I'm having. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you install the MongoDB that is [apparently] a dependency for Node.js but, after creating the image, simply not use it?  Once the image is created you "link" to your other container that has the **real** database in it.    This is just a creative idea; I have no direct experience to support this.

Comment: Which version of OS are you using for you Node container?